# why grep is behaving differently on my home pc and office pc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

when the below code is execute if is detected on my  pc but when i execute the same command on office pc if is not getting detected
what could be possible reason for this ambiguous behavior

$p is one line of text file ,    `xyzxyz if ( abc )`
i am using while read to pass line to grep

```
grep -qw -e 'if(' -e 'if' <<< $p
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then

do something

fi
```

Comment: What OS does your home and office PC run?

Comment: my home pc has linux mint and on office pc , i am using VMplayer running RHEL 6

Comment: if $p is a file, use `<` (only one `<`) rather than (three `<<<` )

Comment: its one line of text file , just like export p='xyzxyz if ( abc )'

Comment: Are you getting any error messages on the RHEL6 machine (or on the Linux Mint machine for that matter)?

Comment: no i am not getting any error messages

Comment: And also, what is the output of `grep -ow -e 'if(' -e 'if' <<< $p` on both systems? (note the `-o`). It should be just `if` I think.

Answer (score 4):

Older versions of `bash` had that bug/misfeature in that in

```
 cat <<< $var
```

The content of `$var` would undergo word splitting (but not globbing) and the resulting words joined with spaces before being put in a temporary file set as input to the `cat` command.

That was fixed in bash-4.4 to align with the other shells supporting that `<<<` zsh operator.

For older versions, that's another case where you need to quote your variables.

So if `$IFS` contained `i` or `f`, that could explain the discrepancy:

```
$ a='if' bash4.1 -c 'IFS=f; cat <<< $a'
i
$ a='if' bash4.4 -c 'IFS=f; cat <<< $a'
if
```

In any case, note that the `-e 'if('` is redundant since if a text contains `if(` as a word, it also contains a `if` word.

Also note that `bash` has regexp matching built-in, so  you can always do

```
re='\<if\>'
if [[ $p =~ $re ]]; then
  printf '"%s" contains a "if" word\n' "$p"
fi
```

(at least on systems like Linux Mint and RHEL where EREs have those `\<`, `\>`, but if your `grep` supports `-w`, it's likely EREs will have `\<` and `\>` as well).

(above is one of those very rare cases where `$p` doesn't need to be quoted (though quoting won't harm), and `$re` *must not* be quoted (otherwise its content is not taken as a regular expression, but as a fixed string))

With standard `sh` syntax, you can also do:

```
case +$p+ in
  (*[^[:alnum:]_]if[^[:alnum:]_]*)
    printf '"%s" contains a "if" word\n' "$p"
esac
```

To get the same effect.